# Dropping pandas rows based on lenght of list in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas dataframe, one of the columns contains list of values like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [11,22,33],
               'B': [[4,5],[10,11,12], []]})
```

Now I want to drop all the rows that have empty lists in column 'B', Can anyone help please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `str.len`

```
df[df.B.str.len()!=0]
Out[223]: 
    A             B
0  11        [4, 5]
1  22  [10, 11, 12]
```

Or

```
df[df.B.astype(bool)]
Out[225]: 
    A             B
0  11        [4, 5]
1  22  [10, 11, 12]
```